# Gradle dont sync in new version Android studio

Tags: android, react-native, build, android-gradle-plugin

i want to run my react native project in android device i tried below gradle settings

**App level build gradle**

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    google()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'

    }
 }

allprojects {
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
    //google()
    maven {
        // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
        url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
    }
   // maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }

    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
       }

    }
 }
```

**Module level gradle**

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile



 project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
 ]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"


def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false


 def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.showstockconnect"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 3
    versionName "1.0.3"
    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
    }

}
splits {
    abi {
        reset()
        enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
        universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
        include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
    }
}
// applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
        // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
        def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
        def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
        if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
            output.versionCodeOverride =
                    versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
           }
        }
     }
 }

 dependencies {
compile project(':react-native-android-location-services-dialog-box')
compile project(':react-native-fetch-blob')
compile project(':react-native-splash-screen')
compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1"
compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
compile project(':react-native-maps')
//noinspection GradleCompatible
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0'

 }


  task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
from configurations.compile
 into 'libs'
}
```

[image]

When i try to generate build i got above error in my android studio ? any idea how can i solve this?

Comment: `compileSdkVersion 26` Don't you have a warning saying that it ignores any API level below 27? It had happened to me this morning (not with react) and I had to downgrade gradle to get my project working again

Comment: malarres : can you post your attempt so i can get idea about that

Answer (score 0):

> can you post your attempt so i can get idea about that

on the left you can see how the `build.gradle` was after the upgrade, and on the right how I left it (downgraded)

[image]

same thing for `gradle-wrapper.properties`
[image]